# How can I blacklist usernames with Devise?

Tags: devise, registration, blacklist

I have Devise setup to allow login with email or username. With your username you can have a vanity URL like so: `vanity.com/username`. My User model thus has `attr_accessible :username` as well as `attr_accessor :login`.

To prevent usernames from colliding with future features, I want to implement a blacklist on certain usernames. You can see a [nice example list in use by GitHub here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-sites-prevent-vanity-URLs-from-colliding-with-future-features).

I'm new to Devise and have searched the how-to's in their wiki to see if this use case or anything like it is covered there. It doesn't seem to be.

**How can I blacklist certain usernames for registration in Devise?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was an easier way to do this than having to modify Devise's controllers.

In the `User` model all I had to do was:

```
validates :username, :exclusion => %w(about blog ...)
```

Way too simple.