# Deny common password on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, passwords

I would like to verify if the password inserted by the user on the registration matches to a list of common password that I have in a file.

For sure, I could save the file in some folder and check whether the inserted one matches against the words in the list, but this would be very bad.

Which do you think the best approach should be?

I am using Rails 4.

Comment: How big is the file? If you have a reasonably sized blacklist, you could try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003546/how-can-i-blacklist-usernames-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table in the database (along with an ActiveRecord model) and populate it from `db/seed.rb` in production